# Google Maps proper padding around markers

Tags: android, google-maps

I've currently got the following code:

```
private void updateCamera() {
    if (markerOptionses.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (LatLng position : markerOptionses.keySet()) {
        builder.include(position);
    }
    final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    MainActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mapView.getParent() != null) {
                        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                                bounds,0                                  );
                        mapView.getMap().animateCamera(cu);
                    }
                }
            }                               );
}
```

This code works perfectly fine to zoom so that all marker positions are exactly inside the view. The problem is however, the top "pin" gets cut off. The point it pins at is exactly shown, but the marker itself isn't.

To fix this, I could add a padding to the CameraUpdate, resulting in something like

```
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,50);
```

This works fine on smaller devices, but on larger devices 50 is too little. If I'd set it to 150, that'd work fine on larger devices but would be way too much on smaller ones.

What would be a good way to solve this problem? Would there be any way to figure out the height of a marker in pixels and use this as padding or so?

Comment: see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16367556/2715073) may be helpful for you.

Comment: work around would be select 50dp and then convert 50dp into pixals, on small devices it would be small no while on high end devices it would be large value. --> code to convert dp to pix : Resources r = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14, r.getDisplayMetrics());

Comment: @Clairvoyant Unfortunately not, there the padding is just specified as `30`.

Answer (score 0):

[See the Android documentation for CameraUpdateFactory#newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int):](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int))

> `padding` space (in px) to leave between the bounding box edges and the view edges. This value is applied to all four sides of the bounding box.

So you need to calculate the size of your markers, which will form the basis of your padding:

```
private int calculateMapMarkerPadding() {
    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) ContextCompat
            .getDrawable(this, R.drawable.map_marker);
    final int width = bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
    final int height = bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
    return (int)Math.round(Math.max(width, height) * MAP_BOUNDS_PADDING);
}
```

Note: Multiply by `MAP_BOUNDS_PADDING` (e.g. 1.2 or 120%) instead of using a fixed amount. And then update your map camera code:

```
    final int padding = calculateMapMarkerPadding();
    final CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), padding);
    mapView.getMap().animateCamera(cu);
```